# Davinci Resolve 16 - Image duration not change

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am new in the field of video production and a new user in Davinci Resolve 16.1.2.026. I want to change the duration of an image in my clip but whatever I tried din't work... My default standard still duration (Menu>Preferences>User>Editing) is 5 secs. But my image in clip lasts only 0.02secs (obviously user can't see anything).

I have also tried to change it using Change Clip Duration (mouse's right click menu) and after that, to Delete gaps (Menu>Edit>Delete Gaps) like the video shown above.
(

)

An other idea is to check out if my image is somehow locked, that's why Davinci cannot modify it, but it isn't.

Any other idea??
Thank you all for the time and the willing!

**Edit:** I resolve this. First of all I change the image's type (jpeg -> png -> jpeg again). Then I re-linked the image.

Don't ask me why it works... It's enough for me that it works! :)

Comment: You should report the issue to BlackMagic.  They're really good about squashing bugs quickly.  Also, FYI, you can change the default duration of imported still images like .jpegs Under Preferences->User->Editing->General Settings->Standard Still Duration.  Cmd/Ctrl-R usually pulls up the Re-time controls for a clip on the timeline, but it didn't work for me with a .jpeg, so I think it's a bug.

Comment: GO TO Menu>Preferences>User>Editing AND CHOICE 1 FRAME (NOT 5 SEC). SHOD HELP RSRS
EXPLAINT ON AN OUTHER VERSION: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ae4xvi47IRs
SEE YOU